# gdal/python：how to fix the polygon self.intersection error?

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, gdal

I want clip raster by shapefile based on GDAL/python platform. However, it is not working.
the code:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal
shpfile="a.shp"
input_file="area.tiff"
output_file = "subarea.tiff"
outTile = gdal.Warp(output_file, input_file, cutlineDSName=shpfile, format="GTiff")
OutTile = None
```

the error:

Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 114.56538630983039 30.263472880169331 outTile = gdal.Warp(output_file, input_file, cutlineDSName=shpfile, format="GTiff") File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\base1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 625, in Warp return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\base1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 3410, in wrapper_GDALWarpDestName return _gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)

ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the shape area looks like it is to assume that the shape intersects (overlaps) with itself, this would create a "negative" area.
The solution is to change a.shp to a valid form.